# Telnet logs not stoping and prompt not visible

Tags: router, telnet

When we do a telnet to an ONU, it gives never-ending console logs and prompt is never appearing. Ctrl+C and many other keyboard commands have been tried but the logs are not stopping. What can be a possible way to stop these logs? 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("*ip*","*port*"))

while True:
    print str(s.recv(1024))
```